# Vue3 CompositionAPI "quizz is not defined" when calling a function from script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

For some reason, I receive "Uncaught ReferenceError: quizz is not defined" if I call a function.

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();

const props = defineProps(["quizz"]);

const navigateToQuiz = () => {
  router.push(`/quizz/${quizz.id}`);
};
</script>
<template>
  <div class="card" @click="navigateToQuiz">
    <img :src="quizz.img" :alt="quizz.name" />
    <div class="card-text">
      <h2>{{ quizz.name }}</h2>
      <p>{{ quizz.questions.length }} questions</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

If I do the router.push directly to the @click, it works and takes me to the next page (/quizz/:id)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `${props.quizz.id}` in your function